# Sorting an array and add elements to a specific place in the index of that array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, addition

I have an array that needs to be sorted but some objects need to be copied also in the new array.

```js
var arr = ["880163305_0010-DI03390REY-D", "880163305_0010", "880163305_0020-DI03390REY-D", "880163305_0020", "880163305_0030-DI03390REY-D", "880163305_0030"];
console.log(arr);

let evenArray=arr.filter((a,i)=>i%2===0);
console.log(evenArray);
```

This is my original array.

```
[
  "880163305_0010-DI03390REY-D",
  "880163305_0010",
  "880163305_0020-DI03390REY-D",
  "880163305_0020",
  "880163305_0030-DI03390REY-D",
  "880163305_0030"
]
```

My new array should be:

```
[
  "880163305_0010-DI03390REY-D",
  "880163305_0010",
  "880163305_0010-DI03390REY-D"
  "880163305_0020-DI03390REY-D",
  "880163305_0020",
  "880163305_0020-DI03390REY-D"
  "880163305_0030-DI03390REY-D",
  "880163305_0030"
  "880163305_0030-DI03390REY-D"
]
```

I've tried to create a second array with only the even in it since these are the ones I need to add.

```js
let evenArray=arr.filter((a,i)=>i%2===0);
```

Than I tried to add evenArray to arr, but I can't find a method for this.
I'm pretty new @this.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you format your code using code blocks so it's easier to read? Also, can you specify the rules of which the array is sorted by? It's not immediately obvious to me.

Comment: The sorted list was provided by a json file and was put in a variable. Now I have to adapt the variable into another variable with the extra codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could `map` through your `evenArray` and return the `i * 2` and `i * 2 + 1` elements from the existing `arr`, followed by the corresponding item of the `evenArray`.

```js
const arr = [
    "880163305_0010-DI03390REY-D", "880163305_0010", 
    "880163305_0020-DI03390REY-D", "880163305_0020", 
    "880163305_0030-DI03390REY-D", "880163305_0030"
];

const evenArray = arr.filter((a, i) => i % 2 === 0);

const result = evenArray.flatMap((a, i) => {
  return [arr[i * 2], arr[i * 2 + 1], a];
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Original array is variable. The build up is the same.
Main number(880163305) is different. ex 880163412.   

Original array:
[
  "880163412_0010-DI03390REY-D",
  "880163412_0010",
  "880163412_0020-DI03390REY-D",
  "880163412_0020",
  "880163412_0030-DI03390REY-D",
  "880163412_0030"
]

My new Array

[
  "880163412_0010-DI03390REY-D",
  "880163412_0010",
  "880163412_0010-DI03390REY-D" 
  "880163412_0020-DI03390REY-D",
  "880163412_0020",
  "880163412_0020-DI03390REY-D"
  "880163412_0030-DI03390REY-D",
  "880163412_0030"
  "880163412_0030-DI03390REY-D"
]

Comment: @TimBrion could you explain a little more? I can't see the difference. Do you want to put the new values in separate arrays?

Comment: The list of the original array is provided by a json file and is put in a variable. Afterwards I want to create a new array with the extra codes. The trick is that the list is variable. The main number (880163305) is always different. The characters behind the _ is always the same. It's a printing list that I want to adapt.

Comment: @TimBrion could you provide the exact input and desired output in your question? With my answer it should work even if the array has a variable length as long as it is in the same format.

Comment: Glad I could help, are you sure this is the expected outcome?

Comment: yes, on a new browser it works, but I have to rewrite it a bit because the software it is used in, doesn't understand the =>. Software doesn't work with ecmascript 6.